# Are there benefits in using Btrfs in a non-RAID setup compared to conventional filesystems?

Tags: filesystems, btrfs, corruption, integrity

Some installation guides recommend using Btrfs for a single root-partition in a non-RAID setup.

Are there any advantages in using Btrfs instead of conventional filesystems (Ext4 / XFS) on a single device?

Is it more likely to detect and / or prevent filesystem corruption?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

btrfs has a lot of advantages over ext4. The most important one is probably the ability to have snapshots and replicate them to another systems. This allows easy rollbacks after an update that introduced problems. Having subvolumes allows you to use different mount options for different parts of your file system in a space efficient way i.e. without having several (e.g. LVM) block devices whose free space cannot be used by the others.

btrfs has checksums for both data and metadata insofar it can detect errors which ext4 cannot detect at all (data corruption) and can detect filesystem corruption more easily. A huge difference is that btrfs is capable of online fsck (there are two levels of fsck, though, and one can be done offline only). Having two instances of the metadata on a single drive makes severe filesystem failure less probable.

On the other hand you still hear (or read, here e.g.) quite unpleasant things about btrfs which you haven't heard about ext3/ext4 in a very long time.

Comment: There's more. I don't want to repeat your useful statements in another answer; and I don't want to write a partial answer – hence the comment. (1) With `cp --reflink=always` I can duplicate any file without taking additional space for data (like with hardlinks), but then edit the copy independently. It's useful for images of faulty disks (e.g. from `ddrescue`). I save the original just in case, I modify the CoW copy: `fsck` and/or whatever. (2) I make images of my pendrive regularly and avoid storing non-modified blocks twice by running `duperemove -d` in the directory that holds the images.

Comment: Thank you, I forgot about snapshots. So there are functional advantages in terms of filesystem integrity. Regarding the "unpleasant things" - I am aware of the RAID 5/6 problems, are there any widespread issues in a non-RAID setup? SUSE systems appear to be using it successfully for this purpose.

Comment: @Bennohouse I cannot say how widespread they are but it seems that you should use only very new versions of btrfs. A few days ago someone explained his btrfs problem here which could not be solved by fsck. Google found a lot of similar descriptions. On the other hand IIRC he did not use metadata redundancy. openSUSE changed quite some time ago to btrfs as default filesystem for the OS but AFAIK they still don't use it for data...